# Filters in custom product collection M2

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, overrides, filter

I have created a new category in backend and fetched products programmatically via override ListProduct block

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Custom\Vendor\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
```

But I want to show filter on this page too. Can anyone advice me how we can do that.

Thanks

Comment: for filter use this block `Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category`

Comment: you can take reference from this file `vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml`

Comment: I tried to you that block in my xml but that doesnt show any filter section. Did you try that?